# How to update an unknown amount of columns in a MySQL-PreparedStatement using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

i have a java function like this:

```
public void update(Integer id, String firstname, 
                   String lastname, Integer age){}
```

Now i want to do an update via preparedstatement on a mysql table, that updates the columns represented by the params of the java function. So i want to do sth like this (in the update function):

```
PreparedStatement = connection.prepare(
   "UPDATE table SET id = ?, firstname = ?, ...");
```

My problem is now, that some params could be NULL, for example, when they dont need to be updated. So at the end i should be able to call ...

```
update(null, "Tom", null, 19);
```

... when i only want the firstname and the age to be updated. So how can i realize this without using multiple statements/rewriting every column?

Comment: Many ORMs offer you Dynamic SQL capabilities to handle this problem. MyBatis is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty common way to create dynamic SQL statements in java is using SQL Builder libraries. They tend to be really easy to use, especially for simple cases like this one. You might wanna check out the libraries [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) and [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/). You could also manipulate the statement strings directly, but I would not suggest that because is error-prone and it brings security risks.